# We have two ways to initiate a web3 instance, which one better we choose?

Tags: ethereum, web3js

I found that there are two ways to create a web3 instance.

1. this comes from the official doc:

```
new Web3(Web3.givenProvider)
```

2. most people use like this:

```
new Web3(window.ethereum)
```

So may i know which way should we choose? And what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 0):

I think window.ethereum is generally for frontend projects and the other is for backend projects. I believe that window.ethereum is a property that MetaMask and similar browser plugins will inject, but obviously aren't available in node.js because there's no window object.

It's possible that some node library is creating a window object but I'm not aware of any.